# ion-slides not showing inside of ion-content and div

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ion-slides

Am new to Ionic framework (Hybrid application development) from iOS native app development. I have to design a screen which should have two button like "`Recent and All`". If we click "Recent" the recent items should be displayed in list and if we click the "All", it should display the all items in the list. Am trying to use the "**`ion-slides`**" control to use two different lists.
I have implemented the ion-slides in the html page inside the "**`ion-view`**", it is overlapping the two buttons (Recent, All buttons are overlapping and not clickable). If I add the "`ion-slides" in "ion-content" or "div", the slides are not in visible`. Also, I need to change the slides based on the button actions if I click the "Recent" button need to show the first slide. I have implemented the "`ionicSlideBoxDelegate`" but, it is not working. How can I fix this issue? Can you please help?

```
<ion-view view-title="Slide Box" ng-controller='homeViewController'>
    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <button ng-click="nextSlide()">Recent</button>
            <button ng-click="previousSlide()">All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-wrapper1">
            <ion-slides pager="false" options="sliderOptions">
                <ion-slide-page>
                    <ion-content>
                        <h1>First Slide</h1>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-slide-page>
                <ion-slide-page>
                    <ion-content>
                        <h1>Second Slide</h1>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-slide-page>
            </ion-slides>
        </div>
    </ion-content> 
</ion-view>
```

Am able see the log "Next Button clicked" but, the action is not performing.

```
.controller('homeViewController', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

  $scope.nextSlide = function() {
    console.log("Next Button clicked", $ionicSlideBoxDelegate);
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    //$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('burgers').next();
  }

  $scope.sliderOptions = {
      effect: 'slide',
      pagination: false,
      initialSlide: 0
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work inside the div. Keep it outside of the div it will work fine.